# Bootstrap 3 align images and links in stacked navigation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to position a small image and its text in the bootstrap stacked navigation, such that text should appear vertically align to the `<img>`.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="side-list"><img height="30" width="30" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-jw84XlLxTYJoFlqzKr5AVoFoDjVwNCakmB5Rtv1UIW3VqG2h"> Stacked List 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="side-list"><img height="30" width="30" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-jw84XlLxTYJoFlqzKr5AVoFoDjVwNCakmB5Rtv1UIW3VqG2h"> Stacked List 2 </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="side-list"><img height="30" width="30" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-jw84XlLxTYJoFlqzKr5AVoFoDjVwNCakmB5Rtv1UIW3VqG2h"> Stacked List 3 </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.side-list{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:11px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block !important;
    color:#000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your **Stacked List** text inside a `<span>`

As:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="side-list">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-jw84XlLxTYJoFlqzKr5AVoFoDjVwNCakmB5Rtv1UIW3VqG2h" height="30" width="30"> <span>Stacked List 1<span></a>
    </li>....
```

and write `CSS`

As:

```
   .nav-tabs > li > a > span {
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: middle; 
    }
```

Here's [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/wp830Lyv/1/)

It will do the trick for you.

Comment: span's parent have to have display: table-cell; to achieve this.

Comment: @kmike please refer my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/wp830Lyv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. I just added the `span` tag around the text and then made them `display:block`.

```css
.side-list {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block !important;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="side-list">
        <img height="30" width="30" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-jw84XlLxTYJoFlqzKr5AVoFoDjVwNCakmB5Rtv1UIW3VqG2h"> <span>Stacked List 1</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="side-list">
        <img height="30" width="30" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-jw84XlLxTYJoFlqzKr5AVoFoDjVwNCakmB5Rtv1UIW3VqG2h"><span> Stacked List 2</span> 
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="side-list">
        <img height="30" width="30" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-jw84XlLxTYJoFlqzKr5AVoFoDjVwNCakmB5Rtv1UIW3VqG2h"><span>Stacked List 3 </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```